# Weird NullPointerException in Groovy inject

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception

```
groovy:000> ['homepages/gg','a','b','c','d'].inject([]) { list, conf -> if (!conf.contains('homepage')) { list << conf.trim() } }
ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException:
Cannot invoke method leftShift() on null object
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:3)
groovy:000> ['homepages/gg','a','b','c','d'].inject([]) { list, conf -> conf.contains('homepage') ? list : list << conf.trim() }
===> [a, b, c, d]
```

Why do I get a `NullPointerException` in the first case but not in the second? I am using Groovy 2.3.7.

Comment: also this can be written as: `theList.findAll{!it.contains('homepages')}*.trim()`

Comment: Thanks! More groovy like :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this code:

```
if (!conf.contains('homepage')) { list << conf.trim() }
```

does not return anything when the condition is not met. There's no `else` to this `if`. If you add an `else` returning a meaningful value, you'll avoid the exception.

The ternary operator, on the other hand, does return a value whether or not the condition is met so this code:

```
conf.contains('homepage') ? list : list << conf.trim()
```

returns an actual object even if `conf` does contain `'homepage'`

To see why this is a problem, take a look at what the [`inject`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject) method does.

To quote the Javadoc:

> Iterates through the given Collection, passing in the initial value to the 2-arg closure along with the first item. The result is passed back (injected) into the closure along with the second item. The new result is injected back into the closure along with the third item and so on until the entire collection has been used.

Now, let's take a look at a slightly modified example. I added a `println` to see what the closure parameters become:

```
 ['homepages/gg','a','b','c','d'].inject([]) { list, conf -> println "[$list, $conf]"; if (!conf.contains('homepage')) { list << conf.trim() } }
```

Running this yields:

```
[[], homepages/gg]
[null, a]
Exception thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method leftShift() on null object

    at ConsoleScript9$_run_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript9:2)

    at ConsoleScript9.run(ConsoleScript9:2)
```

The first call takes the empty array that you pass as the single `Object` parameter and the first element of the list, namely `"homepages/gg"`. This gets passed to the `if` expression. Because the first element, `"homepages/gg"` does indeed contain the string `"homepage"`, the `if` condition is evaluated to false. Because there is no `else`,  *nothing is returned*.

The *nothing*, represented by a `null` reference, returned by the first evaluation of the closure is used in the second evaluation, along with the next element of the list.

`conf` is now equal to `"a`" and `list` is equal to `null`. Further on, you use the `<<` left shift operator on the `null` list (`list << conf.trim()`).

Hence the exception.

Here's a version equivalent to the one that works:

```
['homepages/gg','a','b','c','d'].inject([]) { list, conf ->  if (!conf.contains('homepage')) { list << conf.trim() } else list }
```

The output is as expected:

```
===> [a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks. Definitely helped :)